# How to publish azure function from vs code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-functions-runtime

I have installed [azure-tools-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradygaster.azuretoolsforvscode), but don't know exactly how to use it for publishing the Azure function:

some steps I have tried are:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


PS D:\azurenodejsfunctions>

PS D:\azurenodejsfunctions> func azure login      

PS D:\azurenodejsfunctions> func azure account set <SubscriptionId>

PS D:\azurenodejsfunctions> func azure functionapp publish ..\azurenodejsfunctions\

Publish D:\azurenodejsfunctions contents to an Azure Function App. Locally deleted files are not removed from destination.
Getting site publishing info...
Can't find app with name "..\azurenodejsfunctions\" in current subscription.

PS D:\azurenodejsfunctions>
```

---

I tried the other way , created manually azure function app and then try:

```
PS D:\> func azure functionapp publish azurenodejsfunctions

Exception :
Unable to find function project root. Expecting to have host.json in function project root.
```

Files and folder structure,

[image: Files and folder structure]

Now mystery for me. Any ideas on why this happens & how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and error message, if you want to publish the azure function in the visual studio code. You need firstly create a azure function in the protal, then use the func azure functionapp publish command to publish the function to azure.

I suggest you could follow below way.

1.Install the Azure Tools for Visual Studio Code.

Use ctrl+shift+p open the command and type below command:

```
ext install azuretoolsforvscode
```

2.Create azure function app.

Use ctrl+shift+p open the command and type below command:

```
azure:login

Azure:Create an azure function App(advanced)
```

[image]

3.Use ctrl+shift+c open command window and use below command to install the Azure Functions Core Tools.

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools
```

4.Init the azure function local

Notice: The function name must as same as the function app you have created in the azure

```
func init yourfunctionname
```

5.Locate the function folder

```
cd yourfunctionname
```

6.Use the func azure login and func azure functionapp publish to publish the function

The command like this:

[image]